# Set/Reserve PID

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pid

short question: is there any way to set or reserve an PID (process identifier) for a certain application in linux kernel? I want to start an application with the same PID all time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is answered here : [Run a process to particular/dedicated pid only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131514/run-a-process-to-particular-dedicated-pid-only)

Comment: @talalUcef Thank you very much

Comment: @Bubbleboy you didn't "V" this.